# Printing using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer on iOS and Mobile Safari or Chrome

Tags: ios, angular, pdf, printing, mobile-safari

I have an Angular 7 app that is using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer to render a PDF that I get as a byte array from the web.api. I have no issues rendering the PDF or even printing it from any desktop application. ngx-extended-pdf-viewer as a print button built right in. However, when trying to print from Safari on an iPhone (iOS 12) it only prints a blank page with the url at the bottom. The actual PDF does not print. With Chrome on iOS it doesn't do anything that I can see. I am pretty new to Angular and actually to mobile web development, so perhaps lack of knowledge is getting me. **The PDF viewer is in a mat-tab, so not sure if maybe that is causing some issues??**

I have tried other packages, but they all seem to be based on the same pdf.js code from Mozilla. Also this is the only one I've found so far that has a print. I was thinking about perhaps trying pdf.js outside of an npm package, but so far have not found solid directions on getting this to work in Angular. I'm sure it will, but all directions I have found seem to omit details. Such as, put this code in your app. They just fail to say where in the app.

**From the web.api:**

```
[HttpPost("GetPdfBytes/{PdfId}")]
public ActionResult<byte[]> GetPdfBytesId([FromBody]int id)
{
    string exactPath = string.Empty;
    if (id == 1)
    {
        exactPath = Path.GetFullPath("pdf-test.pdf");
    }
    else if (id == 2)
    {
        exactPath = Path.GetFullPath("DPP.pdf");
    }
    else if (id == 3)
    {
        exactPath = Path.GetFullPath("Request.pdf");

    }
    else
    {
        exactPath = Path.GetFullPath("Emergency Issue.pdf");

    }
    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(exactPath);
    return Ok(bytes);

}
```

**The HTML:**

```
<mat-tab label="PDF">
  <ng-template matTabContent>
      <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer *ngIf="visible[2]" id="pdf3" [src]="pdfSrc3" useBrowserLocale="true" delayFirstView="1000" showSidebarButton="false"
      showOpenFileButton="false" >
      </ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
  </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
getPDFBytesId(id: string) {
  this.getPDFFromServicePdfBytesId(Number(id)).subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
        this.pdfSrc3 = this.convertDataURIToBinary(data);
   },
   error => {
       console.log(error);
   }
 );
}

// hits the web.api

getPDFFromServicePdfBytesId(id: number): Observable<any> {
  const body = id;
  return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:5000/api/values/GetPdfBytes/' + id, body);
}

// converts what we got back to a Uint8Array which is used by the viewer

convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI: string) {
  const raw = window.atob(dataURI);
  const rawLength = raw.length;
  const array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

  for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
  array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: Author of ngx-extended-pdf-viewer here. I've managed to reproduce your bug. It also happens with the default demo of Mozilla. That's really strange because pdf.js simply hides everything except the images containing the PDF rendering. So printing is simply a matter of asking the browser to print images.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7597.

Comment: I've opened a ticket on the bugtracker of ngx-extended-pdf-viewer. Thanks for reporting!
https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues/83